# Download data directly to google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I want to download data from **python application/command** (for eg: youtube-dl or any other **library that download from 3rd party url**) directly to **google cloud storage(Bucket)**.

I have used **gsutil** stream command to stream data directly from process to gcs, but it saves only **console output** to bucket

Also i don't want to mount storage because i want to share that storage with distributed system

Is there any way in which i can download it without downloading on file system first and then copying it to google cloud storage ?

Thanks,

Comment: You can certainly use a tempfile or a NamedTemporyFile, and upload that file to google cloud storage as if it were a regular file. Then use the api to send the files.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, but anyway this seems the only viable option, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation you are describing doesn't seem possible: looking at the documentation and source code for the [Cloud Storage library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_file) in Python only leave you 3 options: upload from file (already in your disk), upload providing a filename (a path to a file already in your disk) and upload from string (upload a text as a .txt file).

You will need to download the file from whichever program you mention (as mentioned in the comments, you can download it to a temporal folder), upload the file to GCS and then delete it from your temporal folder.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to documentation, seems like uploading from disk is the only viable option

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are in search for another technique aside from **gsutil stream** to store into your bucket directly. Considering that you have a command application of Python already. You have a couple of options to achieve your goal:

**Option 1**: Store your data into a python variable then push it into your bucket with the help of  [boto client library plugin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-plugin#uploading-objects) (which uses Python: 2.6.x and 2.7.x )

The Google documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#streaming_uploads_and_downloads_using_python_and_the_boto_plugin) outlines the idea of how to utilize boto within Python ( plus usage examples ).

However, here is copy/paste version of that link with a brief description provided.

**upload:**

dst_uri = boto.storage_uri( + '/' + , 'gs')
dst_uri.new_key().set_contents_from_stream()

**download:**

import sys
src_uri = boto.storage_uri( + '/' + , 'gs')
src_uri.get_key().get_file(sys.stdout)

Where:
*bucket* is your app bucket name that you have set up and *object* being the object you wish to store ( you can find the information for your bucket-name in your GCP console). Also, the great thing about GCS buckets is that you can literally store anything you want into it (i.e: no need to specify what you are storing or encode anything before storing ).

**Option 2**: Store your data using [Google Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python). To be more precise, the functionality that you are looking for in your situation is [uploading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code_sample) with the help of [blob](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_string). ( you can store any form of data inside a blob as well )

Since you do **not** want to save locally and store **directly** into your bucket. It would be my recommendation to use the following method:

upload_from_string(data, content_type='text/plain', client=None, redefined_acl=None)

*(Google definition: Upload contents of this blob from the provided string)*

The important thing to note in this method is that you can set which type of **data** you want to store. Depending on what you are trying to store ( libraries that download from 3rd party url’s ) you can choose between [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) or [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes). However, it would be my recommendation to try bytes first as it allows ASCII characters.