# Upload youtube-dl transcript into Google Cloud storage

Tags: node.js, file-upload, google-cloud-functions, youtube-dl

I am using Youtube-dl to download transcript, it works fine on my machine (local server) where I provide the __Dirname into the Options params to upload files. But I want to use Google Cloud functions, so how can I substitute __dirname with Cloud storage ??
Thank you !!

Comment: Hello Lydia, can you please share with us a mimimal reproducible example of your 
 code to help you with a quick working example?

Comment: After checking [Youtube-dl GitHub](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/22740) looks like someone already responded to your question. However, have you tried to download your transcript locally, and then upload it to Google Cloud Storage? Would this option work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download data directly to google cloud storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624858/download-data-directly-to-google-cloud-storage)

Comment: Hi sllopis, On my machine it works fine, but how can I indicate the local folder "__dirname" in youtube-dl when it is on Google Cloud functions ?

Comment: Can I use a blob rather than __dirname ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload from Youtube-dl it's not possible. To upload files into Google Cloud storage is possible if you upload a file already in your disk.

You will need to download the file from whichever program you mention (as mentioned in the comments, you can download it to a temporal folder), upload the file to GCS and then delete it from your temporal folder.

What you can actually do? you can for example run a script inside of a Google Cloud Instance with a gsutil command to upload the files into a bucket.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I use youtube-dl locally with my local server, it works number one, I just want to put the code on Google Cloud Functions so that I can use it even when I am not on my PC. In the past I tried to use Youtube API to download transcript, but it is not that easy the YT docs are confusing !! do you know any good tutorial that explain how to use YT API to download transcript ? Too bad that I cannot replace "__dirname" with cloud service !!